# ruby function definition not found

Tags: ruby

So I'm a java programmer and I'm trying to get better at ruby, but I'm failing on a basic principle and not getting anywhere.  Here is my class

```
    class Main
      a = Car.new
      a.instance_variable_set("@make", 'Hyundai')

      if a.make == 'Hyundai'
        self.get_hyundai_vehicle_information(a)
      end

      def get_hyundai_vehicle_information(a)
        go_to_hyundai_usa_and_select_vehicle
      end
    end
```

But I keep getting the error

`undefined method 'get_hyundai_vehicle_information' for Main:Class`

Comment: You will need to provide complete code needed to reproduce the issue. This snippet is not enough

Comment: You're running it in the class declaration itself, and the method hasn't been defined yet. Order matters when you're doing stuff *during* class declaration.

Comment: Just put call to `get_hyundai_vehicle_information` after declaration of the fucntion. and sefine it as `def self.get_hyundai_vehicle_information`

Comment: Why are you defining a class `Main`? Why are you setting instance variables and getters in this roundabout, manual way? I don't know Java, but this is exceedingly unidiomatic for Ruby code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are running in the class body is executed in the context of the singleton class of your `Main` class. That basically means, it runs once in the class scope during creation of the class but not in any of the class instances.

Now the method you defined is only available on instances (i.e. it is an instance method). You could define a class method by prepending `self.` to the method name. Then however you would need to define the method before you can call it.

Remember that in Ruby, every piece of code is evaluated in order. That includes class and method definitions. You can't call a method before the code that defines it has been run.